# Adding data to specific row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a script that reads in a spreadsheet of measurements as a `pandas.DataFrame` and adds measurements of the same soundfiles from a second source. I can thus index on the file names, which occur in the spreadsheet as well as the name of the files of secondary measurements.

**Example**:
I have a file called 100.txt which contains some measurements I want to add to the spreadsheet to the row that contains 100.txt in the 'filenumber' column. There is only one such row.

**Problem**: I do not have files for every row in the spreadsheet, i.e. the entries will be something like NA for some data points. So I think I can't just iterate over all my input files?

So far I have tried this (the code is simplified as this is part of a larger script):

```
inputfilis=[u'3-1.txt', u'2-1.txt', '1-1.txt'] 
inputspread=pandas.DataFrame({'col1': ['2', '2', '4'], 'filename':['5-1.txt', u'2-1.txt', '1-1.txt'] , 'col3':['pre', 'pre1', 'pre2']})

for fili in inputfilis:
    matches= [line for line in inputspread['filename'] if line == fili]
#what now???
```

My desired output would be something like this, assuming the external measurements to be added are *12* for 2-1.txt and *20* for 1-1.txt:

```
outputspread=pandas.DataFrame({'col1': ['2', '2', '4'], 'filename':['5-1.txt', u'2-1.txt', '1-1.txt'] , 'col3':['pre', 'pre1', 'pre2'], 'added_column': [NA, 12, 20]})
```

But now I am stuck because I do not know

- how to store the data - add it to the DataFrame somehow, or in a dictionary or similar?
- or is it better to just create a new column of NAs and then replace them with actual values if needed?
- How do I do this?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

### Possible solution

Here is what I have come up with, thanks to Psidom for the help!

```
#add column, fill with NAs
inputspread['added_column']="NA"

#replace NA with actual data whenever match is found
for fili in inputfilis:
    matches= [line for line in inputspread['filename'] if line == fili]     
    inputspread.loc[inputspread[filename]==matches[0], 'added_column']=open(fili, "r").read()
```

If files have more than one item, e.g. tab-separated, we can just do `open(fili, "r").read().split("\t")` at the end. In this case, in the beginning, we can add the right number of columns by doing

```
for h in open(fili, "r").read().split("\t"):
    inputspread[h]="NA"
```

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: @Psidom thanks for pointing it out, I haved added it right below the code. Does that clarify things?

Comment: It does, I think you are looking for something like left join. However, those numbers like 12, 20, where are they from? You are still missing something here.

Comment: @Psidom Hi, yes that's true -- those are the numbers I will read in from the external file. In reality, that is going to be a list of numbers, I just wanted to keep it simple&will add explanation to question. Left join sounds good, I'll look into that!

Comment: How does your 100.txt look like? Can it be read in as a data frame or dictionary such that you have something like `[('2-1.txt', 12), ('1-1.txt', 20)]`?

Comment: @Psidom That is a string i can split into a list (the list will be the same length for all files). I am going to add an idea to my question, if you want to take a look at it?